# Swagger async controller generation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-editor

For a project, I use the swagger hub to build my API. From the swagger hub, I generate the server code. However, when this code is generated it has synchronous controllers. Is there a way to specify in the swagger.yml to generate async controllers instead of synchronous?

- Open Api 3.0.0
- Aps.net Core

*Generated:*

```cs
public virtual IActionResult GetUserById([FromRoute][Required]string userId) { }
```

*Should Be*

```cs
public virtual Task<IActionResult> GetUserById([FromRoute][Required]string userId) { }
```